# ¿ Que hacer cuando el usuario es un vago?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

Puede parecer una pregunta idiota, pero ya llevo varias preguntas contestadas ( y aceptadas ) del tipo ¿ como hago para XXX ?.

Algunas respuestas las he consultado en un buscador, **copiando la frase exacta del usuario**, y me han salido respuestas válidas, en la primera página de resultados, **en perfecto castellano**.

Vamos, que el usuario no se molestó en buscarlo un mínimo por su cuenta; directamente consultó aquí. Un *vago mental*; justamente lo que estoy intentando inculcarle a mis hijos que no sean.

Si esto fuera una lista de correo, se podría argumentar que el usuario no tiene acceso a la web, o está limitado (caso de Cuba), pero esto es una página web, asi que ...

Dudo mucho que ese tipo de preguntas aporten valor al sitio. He visto que varias directamente no han sido contestadas. ¿ Es ese el comportamiento a seguir (el aceptado por la comunidad) ? ¿ se reportan como inapropiadas ? ¿ Se realiza un comentario ?

Comment: No puedes hacer nada al respecto, en este sitio existen diferentes tipos de usuarios, si no te gusta encontrarte con el tipo de usuarios "vagos" y te molesta leer este tipo de preguntas simplemente no respondas y ya :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se que molesta ese tipo do pregunta pero hay que recordar que tal vez haya preguntado algo que no existe en este sitio todavía.  En ese caso, mi argumento sería que vale la pena el contestar la pregunta para poder aumentar la base de datos que estamos juntando aquí.  En un futuro, una persona que encuentre esa pregunta (obvia) vea más contenido útil aquí y se quede a explorar nuestro sitio por más tiempo. Esta es una de nuestras metas, el poder ayudar a la gente que busque respuestas y después se quede a contestar y a contribuir también.

Como se comento, si este tipo de preguntas te molesta demasiado, simplemente hay que ignorarlas. No hay daño en eso tampoco.

Comment: No es que me molesten ... . Es, mayormente, por si había una *política oficial* al respecto; suelen ser preguntas de respuesta fácil y corta, tipo dar un ejemplo de un comando, que tampoco tienen mucho desarrollo posible. Es decir, no son *atascos* a los que se pueda dar una explicación detallada, no son ... *banquetes* de información, son ... galletitas ...

Comment: Claro, se entiende.  Por ahora, no existe una política oficial que digamos.  Tal vez en un futuro haya necesidad de formular algo al respecto.